# error with docker build stage of CodeBuild build

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I am getting the following error from the BUILD stage of my CodeBuild build process:

"Error while executing command: docker build -t ..." Reason: exit status 1

I have a code build service role set up with permissions for ecr, the aws ecr login stage has succeeded, and my buildspec.yml is really simple - pretty much just the standard template. Runtime is the Amazon-managed ubuntu image, standard.

Is there any reason why the Docker build could be failing and anything anyone would suggest to troubleshoot?

Thank you

**Full buildspec.yml file:**

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-west-1)
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Building the Docker image...          
      - docker build -t maxmind:latest .
      - docker tag maxmind:latest 381475286792.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/maxmind:latest      
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker image...
      - docker push 381475286792.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/maxmind:latest
```

**Full error message (BUILD stage):**

```
COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR: Error while executing command docker build -t maxmind:latest .. Reason: exit status 1
```

**Full error message (POST_BUILD stage):**

```
COMMAND EXECUTION_ERROR: Error while executing command: docker push 381475286792.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/maxmind:latest. Reason: exit status 1
```

**Full error message (logstream)**:

```
[Container] 2020/05/20 09:28:54 Running command docker build -t maxmind:latest .
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

[Container] 2020/05/20 09:28:54 Command did not exit successfully docker build -t maxmind:latest . exit status 1
[Container] 2020/05/20 09:28:54 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
```

**Things I have tried**

Attached AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser policy to the codebuild-service-role created by my build process

Comment: Clink into the codebuild project build that failed, and click the 'Phase Details` Tab. Any additional errors there?

Comment: @maafk yes. COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR: Error while executing command: docker build -t... Reason: exit status 1

Comment: Can you provide your codebuild.yml and the full version of the  message?

Comment: @Marcin buildspec.yml and full versions of error messages now added

Comment: You are using incorrect ecr login command. Try that: `$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-west-1)`. Check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-docker.html) how to login to ecr.

Comment: @Marcin thanks for that, now corrected the ecr login command but still getting the same errors when I retry the build

Comment: You should be getting more logs. Check logs of your failed build. It usually produces lots of logs.

Comment: @Marcin would that be in cloudwatch? I have the log to cloudwatch box unchecked at the moment so I will tick that, run again and then try to find the logs

Comment: Just in the code build console. Its colled log trail or something like that.

Comment: [Here](https://blog.boltops.com/img/posts/2019/11/cody-codebuild-build-logs.png) is an example image of the logs in code build.

Comment: @Marcin the logs were greyed out so I enabled the cloudwatch checkbox and now have a log stream that looks like the link you just posted. The error message is:

Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Comment: Interesting. Have you enabled `PrivilegedMode`?

Comment: @Marcin I hadn't enabled it. I have just tried to enable it and update environment, but ran into a permissions issue (`not authorized to perform iam:DeletePolicyVersion on resource CodeBuildBasePolicy-maxmind-build-eu-west-1`) that I will need to resolve before continuing.. I'll update here when I've obtained permissions and retried this. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Ok. Let me know how it will go.

Comment: @Marcin got the needed permissions, updated the environment, retried the build, and everything worked fine - thanks again for the great help

Comment: Nice to hear. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for future reference.

Comment: if getting 'unauthorized' for docker login, notice there are two forms of the command in the 'Files' section [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-docker.html) - the correct one is defined by Marcin [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61893963/error-with-docker-build-stage-of-codebuild-build#comment109498448_61893963)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on the comments.

There were two issues. The first one was not using `PrivilegedMode` mode in the CodeBuild project. The mode is required when building a docker image inside a docker container.

The second issue was missing permission `iam:DeletePolicyVersion`.

Enabling the mode and adding the missing permissions, solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share this in case anyone still has this issue.

This issue can be caused of 3 reasons:

1. Not having `PrivilegedMode` enabled id the CodeBuild project
2. Not having enough `permissions` for the IAM role
3. An error with your `dockerfile` build

In my case it was the 3rd reason.

I **activated s3 logs** which helped me see better error messages as it turned out to be that I was missing a folder in my project which my build dockerfile tried to COPY.

But it can be any error, like running an npm command that doesn't exists.