# Codebuild docker build stage failing

Tags: docker, aws-codebuild

My question is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61893963/error-with-docker-build-stage-of-codebuild-build) where the Docker build stage is failing in Codebuild. However, the buildspec.yml file is a bit different since I'm including additional credentials. Here is my buildspec file:

```
version: 0.2


phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws --version
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region us-west-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
      - REPOSITORY_URI=XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/wp-api
      - COMMIT_HASH=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
      - IMAGE_TAG=build-$(echo $CODEBUILD_BUILD_ID | awk -F":" '{print $2}')
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...
      - docker build -t app:latest --secret id=awscredentials,src=$HOME/.aws/credentials .
      - docker tag app:latest REPOSITORY_URI:latest
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker images...
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
```

The error I get is:

```
[Container] 2022/07/11 18:37:24 Command did not exit successfully docker build -t app:latest --secret id=awscredentials,src=$HOME/.aws/credentials . exit status 1
[Container] 2022/07/11 18:37:24 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2022/07/11 18:37:24 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: docker build -t app:latest --secret id=awscredentials,src=$HOME/.aws/credentials .. Reason: exit status 1
[Container] 2022/07/11 18:37:24 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2022/07/11 18:37:24 Running command echo Build completed on `date`
Build completed on Mon Jul 11 18:37:24 UTC 2022
```

Am I missing something? Note that a more basic buildfile runs fine in the same project environment (one that does not have extra credentials or anything).

Comment: In my experience, most of the time there's more information buried just above the error logs you provided. Things like how the docker build couldn't find some directory, or some command within the dockerfile failed, etc.

Is there anything like that, or did you provide the entirety of the log output?